# How to use localStorage for Google Chrome Extensions?

Tags: html, jquery, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I saved the input from the textarea in localStorage value. This value is in popup.html (i.e., Chrome Extension interface). I'm trying to display the localStorage value in a div in page2.html. This html page is opening in another tab which is full screen (page2.html).

This is the code:

```
# this function uses text from popup.html and tries to display in page2.html
function save() {
    # text is the input from the textarea (popup.html)
    var txt = document.getElementById("text").value;
    
    # using localStorage to save the user input
    localStorage.setItem("text", txt);
    
    # this is the problem -- this doesn't save in the div (in page2.html)
    $('#div').getItem(localStorage.getItem("text"));
}
# listens for the button click (the button is in popup.html -- in chrome extension interface) and then runs the above function
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', save);
```

popup.html

```
<textarea id="text">
# input of the user

</textarea>

<button id="button">
</button>
```

page2.html

```
<div id="div">
# want to display txt value here

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Script in popup.html

```
function save() {
    var txt = document.getElementById("text").value;
    localStorage.setItem("text", txt);
}
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', save);
```

Script in page2.html

```
function ready() {
    $('#div').text(localStorage.getItem("text"));
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! But, this is still not working for me. I created popup.js and page2.js and followed the above code.